# SkiaSharp Draw Bitmap cutting behavior

Tags: maui, skiasharp

A new understanding issue arises while Experimenting with the Canvas.DrawBitmap function. I set up the Rectangle of the Source Part and of the destination via SkRect.Create(). The Problem starts here. I have set the destination Rectangle to be as large as the destination bitmap, which is larger than the source Rectangle. I have gradually enlarged the Space the sourceRectangle takes from 500 by 500 up to 1500 by 1500 with origin coordinates staying at 400 200. The Problem is, the part of the Image that gets shown after the Canvas.DrawBitmap stayed the same always. However, when I make the destination Rectangle as large and with the same coordinates as the source Rectangle i get the Part of the Image i expected to get. What is the Problem here? Do have the destination and source Rectangle have to have the same coordinates and size or is this some kind of caching issue that the displayed part always stays the same, when the destination Rect is of the same Size as the destination Bitmap?

The Cropping logic:

```
[RelayCommand]
    public async void UploadImage()
    {
        //Well i pick a photo for convenience 
        FileResult im = await MediaPicker.Default.PickPhotoAsync();
    
        SKBitmap sourceMap;
        using (Stream s = await im.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await s.CopyToAsync(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                sourceMap = SKBitmap.Decode(ms);
            }
        }
    
        SKBitmap destination = new SKBitmap(1080, 1080);
        var height = sourceMap.Height; //1332
        var width = sourceMap.Width; //2000
        SKRect maxRect = new SKRect(0,0,width,height);
        SKRect sourceRect = SKRect.Create(400, 200, 1500, 1500);
        SKRect destRect = SKRect.Create(0, 0, 1080, 1080);
        using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(destination))
        {
            canvas.Clear();
            canvas.DrawBitmap(sourceMap, sourceRect, destRect);
        }
    
        SKImage skImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(destination);
        SKData encoded = skImage.Encode();
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoded.AsStream().CopyTo(memory);
            Image = memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The associated View:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         xmlns:ImageCroppingTry2="clr-namespace:ImageCroppingTry2"
         x:DataType="ImageCroppingTry2:MainPageViewModel"
         x:Class="ImageCroppingTry2.MainPage">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Image x:Name="displayImage" Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding UploadImageCommand}"></Button>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: Please add to question's code an example of the code lines that do work, vs those that don't. Comment out the lines that do work. I want to see exactly how those one or two code lines differ, between working and not working code. Also, describe exactly what you expected to see, in the version that did not work. And answer these questions (1) Are you trying to **scale** the part you draw, or draw it at original size? (2) Are you expecting something to be drawn in upper-left of destination? (you've specified (0,0) in dest rect, so it will start drawing there.)

Comment: Have you tried using canvas.DrawBitmap to draw cropping image instead of binding? Your case is similar to [Cropping SkiaSharp bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/cropping).

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Do you mean use a canvas as a View and not an Image Tag?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve It is very strange, maybe it was some kind of deployment problem i wanted to recreate the problem again but now it worked. When I encounter it the next time I will update everything with the working and not working code. I am ver sry for this now.

Comment: @WoistdasNiveau Yes, just like the official tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I made a small demo using **MountainClimbers.jpg** in official demo: [Xamarin.Forms - SkiaSharp and Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/SkiaSharpForms/Demos).

This is my xaml file, in **VerticalStackLayout**, I put a canvasview for origin bitmap and also a Image control binds to crop image. The button will trigger the command.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<VerticalStackLayout>
    <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="mycanvas" PaintSurface="SKCanvasView_PaintSurface"   />
    <Button Text="click me to crop" Clicked="myButton_Clicked"></Button>
    <Image x:Name="displayImage" BackgroundColor="Pink" Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}" />           
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

For .cs file, set BindingContext to itself. We know this image is 360 X 480. And I want to crop the 120 X 160 at the central of the image.

```
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
public byte[] image;
public byte[] Image
{

    get
    {
        return image;
    }
    set
    {
        image = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Image));
    }
}

SKBitmap croppedBitmap;
SKBitmap originalBitmap;

public NewPage1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    originalBitmap = BitmapExtensions.LoadBitmapResource(GetType(),"SkiaSharpDrawBitmap75620262.Media.MountainClimbers.jpg");
    this.BindingContext = this;
    mycanvas.HeightRequest = originalBitmap.Height;
}

void SKCanvasView_PaintSurface(System.Object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{

    SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
    SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
    
    canvas.DrawBitmap(originalBitmap, info.Rect, BitmapStretch.Uniform);
    
}

void myButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    croppedBitmap = new SKBitmap(120, 160);
    SKRect dest = new SKRect(0, 0,120, 160);
    SKRect source = SKRect.Create(120, 160, 120 , 160);

    using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(croppedBitmap))
    {
        canvas.Clear();
        canvas.DrawBitmap(originalBitmap,
                          source,dest);  // destination
    }

    SKImage skImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(croppedBitmap);
    SKData encoded = skImage.Encode();
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoded.AsStream().CopyTo(memory);       
        Image = memory.ToArray();
        displayImage.HeightRequest = croppedBitmap.Height;
    }
}
```

}

And the result I think it works as expected:

[image]

Hope my answer makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for this. On this tutorial, however, the CroppingRectangle as well as the destination Bitmap have the same size. My Problem arises when the Cropping Rectangle always has Size 1080 by 1080 and the Cropping Rectangle has a different Size for example 500 by 500. Then, I get the strange behavior I explained in the original Post.

Comment: It also works fine when Cropping Rec and destination have different size. But how to set the image HeightRequest I think make a different. The destination is 1080 but image seems not render such a large size.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. I will look further in it.

Comment: Okay. If you still have any question, feel free to ask. We can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just created a new Question with a follow up problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75788240/skiasahrp-move-rectangle-inversely-to-image-behind