# SkiaSahrp move Rectangle inversely to Image behind

Tags: maui, skiasharp

I have followed following tutorial and your help to understand the cropping behavior of SkiaSharp.DrawBitmap and to be able to move and scale an Image with touchgestures. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch

Following this tutorial i have set up a canvas on my view displaying a bitmap i choose when startign the App. I now have placed a rectangle on Top of this Image and wanted the Rectangle to move inversely to the Image so that the rectangle always stays in place. However i cannot figure out how get the correct transformation matrix so that i can invert it and move the rectangle with it. My Current code looks like follows:

The View:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls"
             xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking;assembly=Maui.FreakyEffects"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageCroppingTry5"
             x:Class="ImageCroppingTry5.CroppingView"
             x:DataType="local:CroppingViewModel"
             Title="CroppingView">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" Grid.Row="0"
                           PaintSurface="canvasView_PaintSurface" />
        <Grid.Effects>
            <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                            TouchAction="TouchEffect_TouchAction" />
        </Grid.Effects>
        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <Button Command="{Binding CropImageCommand}"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding CroppedImage,Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}" WidthRequest="250" HeightRequest="250"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
SKBitmap Bitmap { get; set; }
    Dictionary<long, SKPoint> touchDictionary = new Dictionary<long, SKPoint>();
    SKMatrix matrix;
    CroppingViewModel croppingViewModel;

    SKRect CroppingRect { get; set; }
    SKMatrix Matrix
    {
        get
        {
            return matrix;
        }
        set
        {
            matrix = value;
            SKMatrix m = matrix.Invert();
            CroppingRect = m.MapRect(CroppingRect);
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new MatrixChangedMessage(value));
        }
    }

    public CroppingView(SKBitmap bitmap)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bitmap = bitmap;
        Matrix = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
        this.BindingContext = new CroppingViewModel(bitmap);
        float x = (Bitmap.Width) / 2;
        float y = (Bitmap.Height) / 2;

        float size = 500;

        CroppingRect = SKRect.Create(x - (size / 2), y - (size / 2), size, size);
    }

    private async void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        // Display the bitmap
        canvas.SetMatrix(Matrix);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, new SKPoint());
        canvas.DrawRect(CroppingRect, new SKPaint {
            TextSize = 64.0f,
        IsAntialias = true,
        Color = new SKColor(255, 0, 0),
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill
    });
    }

    private void TouchEffect_TouchAction(object sender, Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking.TouchActionEventArgs e)
    {
        Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking.TouchTrackingPoint pt = e.Location;
        // Convert Xamarin.Forms point to pixels
        SKPoint point =
            new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                        (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));

        switch (e.Type)
        {
            case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                // Find transformed bitmap rectangle
                SKRect rect = new SKRect(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
                rect = Matrix.MapRect(rect);

                // Determine if the touch was within that rectangle
                if (rect.Contains(point) && !touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    touchDictionary.Add(e.Id, point);
                }
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Moved:
                if (touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    // Single-finger drag
                    if (touchDictionary.Count == 1)
                    {
                        SKPoint prevPoint = touchDictionary[e.Id];

                        // Adjust the matrix for the new position
                        SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
                        matrix.TransX += point.X - prevPoint.X;
                        matrix.TransY += point.Y - prevPoint.Y;
                        Matrix = matrix;
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    // Double-finger scale and drag
                    else if (touchDictionary.Count == 2)
                    {
                        // Copy two dictionary keys into array
                        long[] keys = new long[touchDictionary.Count];
                        touchDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

                        // Find index of non-moving (pivot) finger
                        int pivotIndex = (keys[0] == e.Id) ? 1 : 0;

                        // Get the three points involved in the transform
                        SKPoint pivotPoint = touchDictionary[keys[pivotIndex]];
                        SKPoint prevPoint = touchDictionary[e.Id];
                        SKPoint newPoint = point;

                        // Calculate two vectors
                        SKPoint oldVector = prevPoint - pivotPoint;
                        SKPoint newVector = newPoint - pivotPoint;

                        float scale = newVector.LengthSquared/oldVector.LengthSquared;

                        // Scaling factors are ratios of those
                        float scaleX = newVector.X / oldVector.X;
                        float scaleY = newVector.Y / oldVector.Y;

                        if (!float.IsNaN(scaleX) && !float.IsInfinity(scaleX) &&
                            !float.IsNaN(scaleY) && !float.IsInfinity(scaleY))
                        {
                            // If something bad hasn't happened, calculate a scale and translation matrix
                            SKMatrix scaleMatrix = SKMatrix.CreateScale(scale, scale, pivotPoint.X,pivotPoint.Y);
                               // SKMatrix.MakeScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotPoint.X, pivotPoint.Y);
                            SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
                            matrix.PostConcat(scaleMatrix);
                            Matrix = matrix;
                            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                        }
                    }

                    // Store the new point in the dictionary
                    touchDictionary[e.Id] = point;
                }

                break;

            case TouchActionType.Released:
            case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                if (touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    touchDictionary.Remove(e.Id);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel with Cropping logic:

```
 public partial class CroppingViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public SKMatrix matrix;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public SKBitmap cropBitmap;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public byte[] croppedImage;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public SKRect cropRect;

        public CroppingViewModel(SKBitmap cropMap)
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MatrixChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                Matrix = m.Matrix.Invert();
            });
            CropBitmap = cropMap;
        }
        public CroppingViewModel()
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MatrixChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                Matrix = m.Matrix;
            });
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void CropImage()
        {
            float x = (CropBitmap.Width) / 2;
            float y = (CropBitmap.Height) / 2;

            float size = 1000;

            SKRect sourceRect = SKRect.Create(x - (size / 2), y - (size / 2), size, size);
            //SKBitmap destination = new SKBitmap((int)sourceRect.Width, (int)sourceRect.Height);
            //SKRect destRect = SKRect.Create(0, 0, sourceRect.Width, sourceRect.Height);
            SKBitmap destination = new SKBitmap(1080, 1080);
            SKRect destRect = SKRect.Create(0,0,1080,1080);
            sourceRect = Matrix.MapRect(sourceRect);
            using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(destination))
            {
                canvas.Clear();
                canvas.DrawBitmap(CropBitmap, sourceRect, destRect);
            }

            SKImage skImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(destination);
            SKData encoded = skImage.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 100);
            using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoded.AsStream().CopyTo(memory);
                CroppedImage = memory.ToArray();
            }
            
        }

        partial void OnMatrixChanged(SKMatrix value)
        {
            CropRect = value.MapRect(CropRect);
        }
    }
```

I know that there is also a Skiasahrp tutorial showing how to create an Imagecropper but unfortunately that i not how i want my imageCropper to be. I want it to be similar to instagram where i move the Image and then cut a part out. That is where my idea comes from that in the Viewmodel i place a rectangle on top of the Bitmap and transform the rectangle inversely to the transformation of the Bitmap on the View. Unfortunately, however, the Rectangle always moves out of the view quite fast and i cannot find the flaw in the calculation of the transformation matrix.

To avoid confusions: The Rectangle placed on the View is just for debugging reasons so that i can see how the rectangle moves when moving the bitmap.

Comment: I recommend writing a test case that programmatically moves one pixel every second. Start by incrementing x only. Then use debug print statements to print various values. And breakpoints at key places. Should become clearer where the math problem is. If you can't figure it out, add the code and the debug print output to your question. State what the FIRST value that is "wrong" is, and what you expected that value to be. Also write "unit tests" for each of the calculations you do. Don't need an actual test framework; just call a method with various values, and check the result.

Comment: I think there is a difference between your design and Instagram. I think the rectangle don't need to move and only image have to move and scale. The part of image in rectangle then cropped.

Comment: Thank you very much i will try this and look if i can find the error.

@LiqunShen-MSFT You are right on this but with SkiaSharp it seems easier for me to capture the movement of the Bitmap on the View with a Matrix, then invert the Matrix and send it to the ViewModel where i use another Canvas with the same Bitmap and transform the Cropping Rectangle there inversely to the transformation of the Bitmap on the view. This should yield the same result i guess. Or would you recommend another approach?

Comment: It seems to work now but there seems to be a last annoying problem for which i have created a new Question. I would be incredibly thankful if you could help me again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75812913/skiasharp-drawbitmap-randomly-draws-different-bitmap

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Our team will follow up your question.