# SkiaSharp.DrawBitmap randomly draws different Bitmap

Tags: maui, skiasharp

At this point the Image Cropping works almost perfectly well. The only problem now is that the canvas.DrawBitmap method in my ViewModel randomly crops a wrong part of the Bitmap when pressing the Croppign Button although i made sure that weather the Bitmap nor the Cropping- or destination Rectangle change during this time. The dark rectangle in the Image shows the part to be cropped and normally, as you can see, when pressing the button in the middle the right part gets cropped:

[image]

However sometimes when i press the button multiple times without changing anything it Crops weird parts of the image like these:

[image]
[image]

Clicking the Button again gets the expected results but after some presses i get the same strange results. I made sure, however, that weather the Bitmap nor the CroppingRectangle change when pressing the button multiple times. Why is this happening? The console is not telling me anything about this i do not know how i can further debug this?

The View:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" 
                           PaintSurface="canvasView_PaintSurface"/>
        <Grid.Effects>
            <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                            TouchAction="TouchEffect_TouchAction" />
        </Grid.Effects>
        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="ForeGround" Grid.Row="0" Opacity="0.5" PaintSurface="ForeGround_PaintSurface"/>
        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <Button Command="{Binding CropImageCommand}"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding CroppedImage,Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}" WidthRequest="250" HeightRequest="250"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
SKBitmap Bitmap { get; set; }
    Dictionary<long, SKPoint> touchDictionary = new Dictionary<long, SKPoint>();
    SKMatrix matrix;
    SKRect croppingRect;
    SKRect CroppingRect
    {
        get
        {
            return croppingRect;
        }
        set
        {
            SKRect rect = Matrix.Invert().MapRect(value);
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new CroppingRectChangedMessage(croppingRect));
            croppingRect = rect;
        }
    }
    SKMatrix Matrix { get; set; }

    SKSize canvasSize;

    SKSize CanvasSize
    {
        get
        { return canvasSize; }
        set
        {
            if(canvasSize != value)
            {
                canvasSize = value;
                WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new CanvasSizeChangedMessage(value));
            }
        }
    }

    public CroppingView(SKBitmap bitmap)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bitmap = bitmap;
        Matrix = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
        this.BindingContext = new CroppingViewModel(bitmap);
    }

    private async void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();
        CroppingRect = SKRect.Create(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width / 8, canvasView.CanvasSize.Width / 8,
            (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * 0.75), (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * 0.75));

        // Display the bitmap
        canvas.SetMatrix(Matrix);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, new SKPoint());
        CanvasSize = canvasView.CanvasSize;

    }

    private void ForeGround_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {

        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
        
        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint() { Color = SKColor.FromHsl(100, 0, 0), StrokeWidth = 20 };
        canvas.DrawRect(SKRect.Create(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width / 8, canvasView.CanvasSize.Width / 8, 
            (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * 0.75), (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width*0.75)), paint);
    }

    private void TouchEffect_TouchAction(object sender, Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking.TouchActionEventArgs e)
    {
        Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchTracking.TouchTrackingPoint pt = e.Location;
        // Convert Xamarin.Forms point to pixels
        SKPoint point =
            new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                        (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));

        switch (e.Type)
        {
            case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                // Find transformed bitmap rectangle
                SKRect rect = new SKRect(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
                rect = Matrix.MapRect(rect);

                // Determine if the touch was within that rectangle
                if (rect.Contains(point) && !touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    touchDictionary.Add(e.Id, point);
                }
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Moved:
                if (touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    // Single-finger drag
                    if (touchDictionary.Count == 1)
                    {
                        SKPoint prevPoint = touchDictionary[e.Id];

                        // Adjust the matrix for the new position
                        SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
                        matrix.TransX += point.X - prevPoint.X;
                        matrix.TransY += point.Y - prevPoint.Y;
                        Matrix = matrix;
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    // Double-finger scale and drag
                    else if (touchDictionary.Count == 2)
                    {
                        // Copy two dictionary keys into array
                        long[] keys = new long[touchDictionary.Count];
                        touchDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

                        // Find index of non-moving (pivot) finger
                        int pivotIndex = (keys[0] == e.Id) ? 1 : 0;

                        // Get the three points involved in the transform
                        SKPoint pivotPoint = touchDictionary[keys[pivotIndex]];
                        SKPoint prevPoint = touchDictionary[e.Id];
                        SKPoint newPoint = point;

                        // Calculate two vectors
                        SKPoint oldVector = prevPoint - pivotPoint;
                        SKPoint newVector = newPoint - pivotPoint;

                        float scale = newVector.LengthSquared/oldVector.LengthSquared;

                        // Scaling factors are ratios of those
                        float scaleX = newVector.X / oldVector.X;
                        float scaleY = newVector.Y / oldVector.Y;

                        if (!float.IsNaN(scaleX) && !float.IsInfinity(scaleX) &&
                            !float.IsNaN(scaleY) && !float.IsInfinity(scaleY))
                        {
                            // If something bad hasn't happened, calculate a scale and translation matrix
                            SKMatrix scaleMatrix = SKMatrix.CreateScale(scale, scale, pivotPoint.X,pivotPoint.Y);
                            SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
                            matrix = matrix.PostConcat(scaleMatrix);
                            Matrix = matrix;
                            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                        }
                    }

                    // Store the new point in the dictionary
                    touchDictionary[e.Id] = point;
                }

                break;

            case TouchActionType.Released:
            case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                if (touchDictionary.ContainsKey(e.Id))
                {
                    touchDictionary.Remove(e.Id);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public partial class CroppingViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public SKMatrix matrix;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public SKBitmap cropBitmap;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public byte[] croppedImage;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public SKRect cropRect;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public SKRect croppingRect;

        SKSize CanvasSize { get; set; }
        public CroppingViewModel(SKBitmap cropMap)
        {
            Matrix = SKMatrix.Identity;
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<CanvasSizeChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                CanvasSize = m.CanvasSize;
            });
            CropBitmap = cropMap;
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<CroppingRectChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                CroppingRect = m.CroppingRect;
            });
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void CropImage()
        {
            SKBitmap destination = new SKBitmap(1080, 1080);
            SKRect destRect = SKRect.Create(0,0,1080,1080);
            using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(destination))
            {
                canvas.Clear();
                canvas.SetMatrix(Matrix);
                canvas.DrawBitmap(CropBitmap, CroppingRect, destRect);
            }

            SKImage skImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(destination);
            SKData encoded = skImage.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 100);
            using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoded.AsStream().CopyTo(memory);
                CroppedImage = memory.ToArray();
            }
            
        }

    }
```

used Nuget Packages:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the nuget packages you use in this project?

Comment: Keeping touchDictionary to follow touches seems like a bad idea and prone to errors. Which Ctor do you use? Because one registers to Matrix changing and the other does not.

Comment: I added the nuget Packages in the original Posts but apart from thedefault Maui Packages i only installed SkiaSharp, the Community Toolkit and FreakyEffects as the replacement for the TouchEffects used by the SkiaSharp tutorial for xamarin forms. https://github.com/FreakyAli/MAUI.FreakyEffects

I used the TouchDictionary since it was also used in the tutorial i followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch . If you know a better approach with less errors i would be glad. I also removed the unnecassary ctor.

Comment: Could this be some kind of an Emulator Problem? I have just tried debugging it on my mobile Phone and did not encounter this issue. It would be nice though to understand why this happens on the emulator.

Comment: This might be the NuGet package's problem on Emulator.  That is why recommend the developers to use the physical device.